# React Hook / How to pause & continue my timer?

Tags: react-hooks

Hello
I am working on a timer in React to understand how Hooks works, and so far everything is ok except the start button (in my case the timer starts automatically and start button should be use with pause). I can't figure how to resolve this problem with these hooks.

```js
const { useRef, useState, useEffect } = React;

function Minuteur() {
  const intervalRef = useRef();
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(30);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((oldTimer) => oldTimer - 1);
    }, 1000);
    intervalRef.current = id;
  }, []);

  const stopTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  };

  const resetTimer = () => {
     setTimer(30)
  };
  
  const playTimer = () => {
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Il reste : {timer} secondes</p>
      <button onClick={playTimer}> PLAY! </button>
      <button onClick={stopTimer}> STOP! </button>
      <button onClick={resetTimer}> RESET! </button>
    </div>
  );
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/moiamy/pen/jOxQmQj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Minuteur() {
  // Définition de la référence
  const intervalRef = useRef();
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(30);
  const [timerRunning, setTimerRunning] = useState(false); // I added a state for if the timer should be running or not

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;
    if (timerRunning) { // Check if the timer is running
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer(timer => timer - 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
      
  }, [timerRunning]); // rerun side effect when timerRunning changes

  // Fonction permettant d'arrêter le ‘timer’
  const stopTimer = () => {
    setTimerRunning(false) // Set running to false
  };

  const resetTimer = () => {
    setTimer(30);
    stopTimer();
  };
  
  const playTimer = () => {
    setTimerRunning(true); // set running to true
  };
  ...
}
```

Edit: Everything in the [] dependency array at the end of the useEffect hook is what the side effect "watches". So by adding the timerRunning to the dependency array the useEffect hook will watch for the timerRunning and when it changes, it will cause the hook to re-render. If it is an empty array then it will only ever run on the initial load. That is why your timer started on refresh.